# React tic-tac-toe game

Tags: reactjs

I started learning react today, and I followed the tutorial on reactjs.org. The most part is understandable but I can't understand how the winner is calculated... I'll include the whole code below, but my problem is with the calculatewiner function. I would be glad if someone could explain the logic behind it.

```js
function Square(props) {
    return ( <
        button className = "square"
        onClick = {
            props.onClick
        } > {
            props.value
        } <
        /button>
    );
}

class Board extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            squares: Array(9).fill(null),
            xIsNext: true,
        };
    }

    handleClick(i) {
        const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
        squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
        this.setState({
            squares: squares,
            xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext,
        });
    }

    renderSquare(i) {
        return ( <
            Square value = {
                this.state.squares[i]
            }
            onClick = {
                () => this.handleClick(i)
            }
            />
        );
    }

    render() {
        const winner = calculateWinner(this.state.squares);
        let status;
        if (winner) {
            status = 'A győztes: ' + winner;

        } else {
            status = 'Következő játékos ' + (this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');
        }

        return ( <
            div >
            <
            div className = "status" > {
                status
            } < /div> <
            div className = "board-row" > {
                this.renderSquare(0)
            } {
                this.renderSquare(1)
            } {
                this.renderSquare(2)
            } <
            /div> <
            div className = "board-row" > {
                this.renderSquare(3)
            } {
                this.renderSquare(4)
            } {
                this.renderSquare(5)
            } <
            /div> <
            div className = "board-row" > {
                this.renderSquare(6)
            } {
                this.renderSquare(7)
            } {
                this.renderSquare(8)
            } <
            /div> <
            /div>
        );
    }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return ( <
            div className = "game" >
            <
            div className = "game-board" >
            <
            Board / >
            <
            /div> <
            div className = "game-info" >
            <
            div > {
                /* status */ } < /div> <
            ol > {
                /* TODO */ } < /ol> <
            /div> <
            /div>
        );
    }
}



ReactDOM.render( <
    Game / > ,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

function calculateWinner(squares) {
    const lines = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6],
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
        if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
            return squares[a];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: lines represent the 8 different lines to win (3 horizontal, 3 vertical, 2 diagonal). Eg: The top row is formed by the cells [0,1,2]. So if all of this cells contain the same symbol, it means that player has 3 in a row. So the code is checking that all three cells contain the same, and that they are actually not empty (3 empty cells is not a winning position)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is `lines` variables looks 'unordered' but if you think in a table like this:

```sh
|---|---|---|  
| 0 | 1 | 2 |  
|---|---|---|  
| 3 | 4 | 5 |  
|---|---|---|  
| 6 | 7 | 8 |  
|---|---|---|
```

The winner combinations are: 0-1-2 ; 3-4-5 ; 6-7-8 ... and so on.

So in `calculateWinner` method, there is a loop to iterate over every possible combination and check if in each position there is the same value/player.

If comparisons are `true`, then there is a winner that is returned.

Checking the code (inline commented)

```js
// Iterate over every possible combination
for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    // Get values from line
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    // Compare each value
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
        // If three comparisons are true it returns squares[a] value: 'X' or 'O'
        return squares[a];
    }
}
```

Comment: cells contain either `X` or `O`, not `true`

Answer (score 0):

We win with O or X in the specific order -> 0-1-2 ; 3-4-5 ; 6-7-8 and so on , the nos.(0,1,2) represent the position in the matrix , so we are checking for this pattern for either O or X if we find this pattern of repetition of values in the above given sets then we will declare the winner by selecting any 1 of the index as all index in that set has same value so for simplicity we are returning the value in the first cell where the repetition started i.e. square[a] Note: the updated square is passed continuously as state changes .